# AngularJS $apply not working after ngChange on input type range

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is allowed or possible but basically I have a simple audio player using the html5 audio element.

```
app.factory('audio', function($document) {
    var audio = $document[0].createElement('audio');
    return audio;
});
```

Then on my view, I have a range input for seeking

```
<input id="seek" type="range" min="0" ng-model="seek" ng-change="seeked()" max="{{max}}" value="{{seek}}">
```

On my controller, I have the following:

```
app.controller('PlayerController', function($rootScope, $scope, audio) {

    //triggered by ngChange to update audio.currentTime
    $scope.seeked = function(){
        audio.currentTime = this.seek;
    };

    $scope.updateUI = function(seek, max){        
        $scope.max = max;
        $scope.seek = seek;
    };

    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
        seek = audio.currentTime;
        max = audio.duration;          
        $rootScope.$apply($scope.updateUI(seek, max));           
    });
}
```

My problem is, when I hit play, the range input element is updating which is what I want. But when I change the input value (move the slider/seek), the song jumps exactly to where I placed the slider but the slider doesn't update anymore after.

Another approach I did for this was to use jqLite and update the input range value inside the 'timeupdate' event with the following:

```
angular.element('#seek').val(audio.currentTime);
```

This works great, but I want to avoid using jqLite as much as possible unless there's no other work-around for this. Can someone enlighten me about this? BTW, I'm using Ionic Framework and I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: have you tried calling the $apply in the seeked function after changing the currentTime?

Comment: @JaredReeves, you mean call $apply again in seeked()?

Comment: Yes, it is possible that the other apply is run before that value change in seeked. I am not sure if this will work, it is just a suggestion.

Comment: It didn't. Log says: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Comment: also a better solution to calling $rootScope.$apply(), would be to wrap(code in "timeupdate') it in a $timeout with no interval set. by doing this it forces a digest cycle after the $timout call

Comment: Ok, now you know that the $rootScope.$apply is in progress, and there might be some timing issues between the apply and the seeked

Comment: try and remove the apply in the listener and just have the one in seeked

Comment: The input won't update continuously during playtime as the seeked() will only be called once a 'seek' action occur. I will read on that $timeout option and try an implementation.

Comment: looking at this further i dont think the timeout will work in your case in the listener, but might work in the seeked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the issue.

Source of answer can be found [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/working-with-ng-model-and-input-type-range/949).

According to him(Calendee), dot notation and prototypal inheritance should be observed always.

So I updated my view into the ff:

```
<input type="range" min="0" ng-model="data.seek" ng-change="seeked();" max="{{max}}" value="{{data.seek}}">
```

Then on my controller:

```
app.controller('PlayerController', function($timeout, $scope, audio) {

    //init vars
    $scope.data = {};

    //triggered by ngChange to update audio.currentTime
    $scope.seeked = function(){
        audio.currentTime = this.data.seek;
    };

    $scope.updateUI = function(seek, max){        
        $scope.max = max;
        $scope.data.seek = seek;
    };

    audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
        seek = audio.currentTime;
        max = audio.duration;

        //did a little change here by using $timeout         
        $timeout(function(){
            $scope.updateUI(seek, max)
        }, 0);           
    });
}
```

Additional references can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).